# JavaScript perform event after onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I wanted to bind a save function to happen *after* a click.
The **mouseup** event happens just before the checkbox/radiobox changes. I need to let the checkbox/radios change before the event calls my function.

Is there some other event I need to bind to? or is it something simple like **e.doDefaults()**

```
$(this).find('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    $(this).bind('mouseup', function (e) {
        // console.log(all teh checked)
        // saveData(id)
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you use onmousedown?

Comment: I thought he just wanted [`mouseup`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/), OP can you be more clear on what the end goal is?

Comment: oops. coming back like 3 days later, I dont even know what I was asking. I fixed it.

Comment: Then consider providing your solution here for others to see.

Comment: Sorry,  Imeant I fixed my question. XD  I dont have a fix to the solution yet.